# Limiting number of different kind of results in mongoDB aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to write an aggregation that take the following documents:

```
{ type: "dog", name: "Charlie" }
{ type: "dog", name: "Felix" }
{ type: "dog", name: "John" }
{ type: "cat", name: "Tum" }
```

And returns **up to 2** of each kind, not grouped in any separate way:

```
{ type: "dog", name: "Charlie" }
{ type: "dog", name: "Felix" }
{ type: "cat", name: "Tum" }
```

Meaning just **up to** two cats plus **up to** two dogs. Does grouping and limiting the way to go here? If so - how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the documents by `type`, create a list of the `names` per group, **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)** the list to only have two elements with **[`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/)** and then flatten the list using **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)**, something like the following:

```
Model.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$type",
        "data": { "$push": "$name" }
    } },
    { "$project": {
        "type": "$_id",
        "name": { "$slice": ["$data", 2] }
    } },
    { "$unwind": "$name" }
]).exec(callback);
```